# Django Login fails with ValueError: unknown reasons

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication, pycrypto, django-login

I am getting a strange error when trying to log in. This happens when logging in to admin as well.

ValueError: unknown reasons

The Stack Trace is at http://dpaste.com/3S8ZFJC

Basically its this line in crypto.py that is failing

```
return hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
            digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen)
```

This is in Django-1.9.5 with Python 2.7.9 on RHEL 5.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a centos 5.8 with python 2.7.12 and I add to change the password hashers in django settings.

by default it is :

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

I changed it to :

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

I don't think using MD5 is good enough so I'm looking to find what system library could be missing. You wil also need to create new users or superusers bacause it you have already create some their passwords won't have the right encryption.